# how to read each value of a column in a table

Tags: axapta, x++

Using x++ how to create a job to read each value of a column in a table in Microsoft dynamics AX 2009?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:  in the AOT (Ctrl-D) right-click on `Jobs` and select `New Job`. In the new window enter something like (using the correct table and column name you want to read):

```
static void Job()
{
    YourTable  yourTable;
    ;
    while select TheColumn from yourTable
    {
        // process yourTable.TheColumn
        info(strFmt("value: %1", yourTable.TheColumn));
    }
}
```

but thera are some other ways: [Select Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa845764.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This code will display all the column values for a record.

```
static void Job1(Args _args)
{
    DictTable   dictTable = new DictTable(tableNum(CustTable));
    DictField   dictField;
    int         counter, fieldId;

    CustTable   custTable;
    anytype     value; 

    select firstonly custTable;

    for (counter = 1; counter <= dictTable.fieldCnt(); counter++)
    {
        fieldId = dictTable.fieldCnt2Id(counter);
        dictField = new DictField(tableNum(CustTable), fieldId);

        if (!dictField.isSystem())
        {
            value = custTable.(fieldId);
            if(value)
            {
                info(strFmt('%1 = %2', 
                            dictField.label(),
                            any2str(value)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For getting all the values for a specific column, please use Carlos Heuberger's code.

Answer (score -1):

Just a slight mod, took out `any2str` to make my table work:

`strFmt('%1 = %2 \r\n', dictField.label(), value);`